# Java - Extract the keys from JSON object in to a string whose values are true

Tags: java, json

From below json object i have to extract all the keys where the values are true.

```
{
  "result": {
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Success",
    "messages": [
      "Operation completed successfully."
    ]
  },
  "recommendedAction": "NA",
  "vendorEvaluationReport": {
    "bioCatchEvaluation": {
      "sessionId": "79634aa0-1639-11ec-84b0-db18703348d3",
      "score": 624,
      "fraudEvaluationResult": "tested",
      "muid": "1624647875970-F12CF03A-9ADC-4C6E-8F3F-6826220B2607",
      "threatIndicators": {
        "isBot": false,
        "isEmulator": false,
        "isRat": false
      },
      "riskFactors": {
        "expertUser": {
          "advancedKeyCombo": true
        },
        "lowDataFamiliarity": {
          "importData": true
        },
        "riskyEvent": {
          "recentProfileSettingsChange": true
        }
      },
      "genuineFactors": {
        "genuineLocation": {
          "consistentIP": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the extracted values to be in an `String array = [advancedKeyCombo, importData, recentProfileSettingsChange, consistentIP]`

Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Examine all of the keys, find the ones whose value is set to `true`, and add those to a List<String>.  List<String> has a `toArray()` method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is walking the JSON tree and examining each node to determine if it is a BooleanNode or not.

This code will produce a List of node names that are of BooleanNode type AND have a true value:

```
    @Test
    public void test4() throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69224118/java-extract-the-keys-from-json-object-in-to-a-string-whose-values-are-true
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final InputStream jsonStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test4.json");
        final JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonStream);
        final List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        walkJsonTree("root", root, nodes);
        System.out.println(nodes);
    }

    private void walkJsonTree(final String name, final JsonNode node, final List<String> trueNodes) {
        if (node.isObject()) {
            final ObjectNode n = (ObjectNode) node;
            final Iterator<String> it = n.fieldNames();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                final String fn = it.next();
                walkJsonTree(fn, n.get(fn), trueNodes);
            }
        } else if (node.isArray()) {
            final ArrayNode n = (ArrayNode) node;
            final Iterator<JsonNode> it = n.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                walkJsonTree("array", it.next(), trueNodes);
            }
        } else if (node.isBoolean()) {
            final BooleanNode n = (BooleanNode) node;
            if (n.booleanValue()) {
                trueNodes.add(name);
            }
        }
    }
```